# HTML Multiple select change 'None selected' text

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a select list with multi select option:

```
<select data-bind="attr:{'id':'multilistS'+Id()},foreach: Hlist" multiple="multiple">
     <option data-bind="click:$root.changeShole,value:$data.Id, text:N,attr:{'selected':$data.Sel}">Cheese</option>
</select>
```

but I want to change the 'None Selected' text. It is possible to do this in HTML code or just in JavaScript using `nonSelectedText` option?

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html should answer this question. Let me know if it doesn't and I can make a demo.

Comment: Thanks John Pavek for your advice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should take John Pavek's advice to read up on the options bindings. Knockout provides good tools specifically for this, and your construction uses none of them.

`noneselectedtext` appears to be a feature of the [jQuery-UI multiselect widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget). If you are using that, then you will want to use a [binding handler for it](https://gist.github.com/ssajous/5823594).

Here is a simple example of what you describe, with a message that changes based on whether anything in the multiselect is selected.

```js
const vm = {
  optionsCaption: ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return (vm.selectedOptions().length === 0) ? 'Please select at least one' : 'ok';
  }),
  selectedOptions: ko.observableArray([]),
  Hlist: ko.observableArray([{
    Id: 1,
    N: 'One'
  }, {
    Id: 2,
    N: 'Two'
  }])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="text: optionsCaption"></div>
<select data-bind="options: Hlist, optionsText: 'N', optionsValue: 'Id', selectedOptions: selectedOptions" multiple="multiple">
</select>
<div data-bind="foreach: selectedOptions">
  <div data-bind="text:$data"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did that and it worked. Forgot to mention :) I've used optionsCaption and it worked ok

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is initially the field says "None Selected". When the user selects some options, the text changes. Is that correct? If yes, this might work:

```
<option disabled selected> value>None Selected</option>
```

Comment: Not initially. Every time a user unchecks all the options this message is displayed.

Comment: It's not an option. It's just a message that is displayed when no option is checked